# CSS styles not applied to Mailchimp form

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mailchimp

I have edited the style of an embedded Mailchimp form for my WP website. However, when I apply the changes to my website's `footer.php` and `style.css`, the form looks completely unstyled:

[image: Unstyled Mailchimp form]

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wjx8skah/) in which you can see the style of the form I aim to apply.

You can also see the code here:

```css
/* Changes the style of the overall form */

#mc_embed_signup {
  background: #c2cdc8;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Styles the header text above the inputs */

#inscripcion {
  font-size: 18px;
  font: Poppins, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
}

#mc_embed_signup form {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

.mc-field-group {
  display: inline-block;
}


/* positions input field horizontally */

#mc_embed_signup input.email {
  font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
  border: none;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #343434;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
}

#mc_embed_signup input.email:focus {
  outline-color: #FAE105;
}

#mc_embed_signup label {
  display: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#mc_embed_signup .clear {
  display: inline-block;
}

#mc_embed_signup .button {
  background-color: #224b37;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: none;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 2px;
  transition: all 0.23s ease-in-out 0s;
}

#mc_embed_signup .button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#mc_embed_signup div#mce-responses {
  float: left;
  top: -1.4em;
  padding: 0em .5em 0em .5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 5%;
  clear: both;
}

#mc_embed_signup div.response {
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 1em .5em .5em 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  top: -1.5em;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 80%;
}

#mc_embed_signup #mce-error-response {
  display: none;
}

#mc_embed_signup #mce-success-response {
  color: #529214;
  display: none;
}

#mc_embed_signup label.error {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 1.05em;
  text-align: left;
  padding: .5em 0;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #mc_embed_signup input.email {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  #mc_embed_signup .clear {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #mc_embed_signup .button {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
  <form action="https://imthemoisturizer.us19.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=13cc95dc908756ea974c0f4fb&amp;id=78f2b1b6c1" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
      <div id="inscripcion">¿Quieres recibir todos mis posts? ⦙ Do you want to receive my posts?</div>
      <input type="email" value="" "style=background:#FFFFFF;" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email" required>
      <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
      <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_13cc95dc908756ea974c0f4fb_78f2b1b6c1" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
      <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="OK!" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

What's wrong with this code? Something must be blocking all styles, but I can't see what.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: @Sfili_81 why did you edit my question if the changes won't help provide a better understanding on the issue? It was alright as per the Stack Overflow guidelines and the "titles" I added may help others who aren't as fluent as myself.

Comment: Because a snippet can help to read your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, if I included the HTML on `footer.php` and the CSS on `style.css`, the styles didn't properly load and the form had an awful appearance.

Perhaps this isn't a neat or clean solution, but it works and now my Mailchimp form is properly styled. I simply included the styles right at the beginning of the `div` for the form and now they appear smoothly. I did it with this code, included on `footer.php`:

```
<!-- Begin Mailchimp Signup Form -->
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<style>
/* Changes the style of the overall form */
#mc_embed_signup {
    background: #c2cdc8;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 45px;
        text-align: center;
}
   
  /* Styles the header text above the inputs */
#inscripcion {
    font-size: 16px;
    font: Poppins,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
}

#mc_embed_signup form {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
.mc-field-group {
  display: inline-block; 
} /* positions input field horizontally */

#mc_embed_signup input.email {
 font-family: Poppins,sans-serif;
  border: none;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #343434;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block; 
}

#mc_embed_signup input.email:focus {
  outline-color: #FAE105;
}
#mc_embed_signup label {
  display: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#mc_embed_signup .clear {
  display: inline-block;
}

#mc_embed_signup .button {
  background-color: #224b37;
  color: #ffffff;
  font: Poppins, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: none;
  padding: 0 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 14px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 2px;
  transition: all 0.23s ease-in-out 0s;
}
#mc_embed_signup .button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#mc_embed_signup div#mce-responses {
  float: left;
  top: -1.4em;
  padding: 0em .5em 0em .5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 5%;
  clear: both;
}
#mc_embed_signup div.response {
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 1em .5em .5em 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  top: -1.5em;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 80%;
}
#mc_embed_signup #mce-error-response {
  display: none;
}
#mc_embed_signup #mce-success-response {
  color: #529214;
  display: none;
}
#mc_embed_signup label.error {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 1.05em;
  text-align: left;
  padding: .5em 0;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #mc_embed_signup input.email {
      width: 100%;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  #mc_embed_signup .clear {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
  }
  #mc_embed_signup .button {
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0; 
  }
}
</style>
<form action="HERE GOES THE LINK TO YOUR MAILCHIMP FORM" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
    <div id="inscripcion">¿Quieres recibir todos mis posts? ⦙ Do you want to receive my posts?</div>
    <input type="email" value="" "style=background:#FFFFFF;" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email" required>
    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
   <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_13cc95dc908756ea974c0f4fb_78f2b1b6c1" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
<div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="OK!" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Change it so that it adapts to your needs and preferences and it should work, although I can't guarantee that it's a clean solution.